# Type I error in t tests and LRT

Tags: t-test, likelihood-ratio

In situations where unequal variance t-test is appropriate, if we use equal variance t-test, type I error would be inflated. I created a likelihood ratio test (LRT) equivalent of unequal variance t-test, but for some reason, it performs poorly (i.e., worse than equal variance t-test). This problem persists even if I increase the sample size to be fairly large (n=100). I don't want it to be just because of the sample size...

```
NL0 <- function(p,x1,x2){
   l1 <- -sum(dnorm(x1,p[1],p[2],log=T))
   l2 <- -sum(dnorm(x2,p[1],p[3],log=T))
  l1+l2
}

NL1 <- function(p,x1,x2){
   l1 <- -sum(dnorm(x1,p[1],p[3],log=T))
   l2 <- -sum(dnorm(x2,p[2],p[4],log=T))
  l1+l2
}

nsim <- 1000
out1 <- out2 <- out3 <- rep(NA,nsim)
n1 <- n2 <- 20
m1 <- m2 <- 100
s1 <-  1
s2 <- 10

for(i in 1:1000){
x1 <- rnorm(n1,m1,s1)
x2 <- rnorm(n2,m2,s2)

L0 <- optim(c(mean(c(x1,x2)),sd(x1),sd(x2)),NL0,x1=x1,x2=x2)$value
    L1 <- optim(c(mean(x1),mean(x2),sd(x1),sd(x2)),NL1,x1=x1,x2=x2)$value

# Test staistic
D <- 2*(L0-L1)
out1[i] <- t.test(x1,x2,var.equal=TRUE)$p.value
    out2[i] <- t.test(x1,x2,var.equal=FALSE)$p.value
out3[i] <- 1-pchisq(D,1)
}

mean(out1<0.05)  # equal variance t-test
mean(out2<0.05)  # unequal variance t-test
mean(out3<0.05)  # likelihood ratio test
```

Comment: "*In situations where unequal variance t-test is appropriate, if we use equal variance t-test, type I error would be inflated*" --- not quite. If the smaller sample has larger variance, type I error is inflated, but if the *larger* sample has larger variance, type I error is decreased from the nominal. If the two samples are equal in size, type I error is pretty much right.

Comment: @Glen_b `n1 <- 10; n2 <- 20; s1 <- 10; s2 <- 1` made the result more like I initially expected. I now understand the relationship among these four values is important.